# Real past conditional: If a person grew up in the 90s, he will love the movie

Tags: grammar, conditionals

The scenario is like this: I just taught a group of students yesterday, and I am talking about it to my friend right now today.
I used real past conditional to talk about yesterday's lesson. And Example 1 is the sentence. Is Example 1 correct?

**Example 1:**

> Me: If my students enjoyed the lesson yesterday, they will love my next lesson tomorrow.

The scenario is like this: I want to say people who grew up in the 90s are going to love the new movie, and I want to use real past conditional to talk about it. And Example 2 is the sentence. Is Example 2 correct?

**Example 2:**

> Me: (a) If a person grew up in the 90s, he will love the movie.

> Me: (b) If one grew up in the 90s, one will love the movie.

Comment: Both (a) and (b) are grammatical, though it would be more usual to use _you_ than the more formal _one_.

Comment: Thank you. How about Example 1.

Comment: Oh, sorry - yes, it is.